# unable to insert primary key in mysql table

Tags: mysql, xampp, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm a complete beginner in sql and I am using mysql xampp server where I have a customers table and a bookings table . I use mysql data modeler with a ddl to generate the code that creates these tables .
This is how my 2 tables are created below:

BOOKING TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE booking (
    booking_id             INTEGER NOT NULL,
    b_city                 VARCHAR(30),
    b_date                 DATETIME,
    departure_date         DATETIME,
    arrival_date           DATETIME,
    dep_time               DATETIME,
    arr_time               DATETIME,
    seat_type              VARCHAR(30),
    flight_cost            DOUBLE,
    total_cost             DOUBLE,
    booking_state          VARCHAR(2),
    deposit                DOUBLE,
    price_remenant         DOUBLE,
    customer_customer_id   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    flight_id              INTEGER,
    customer_customer_id1  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL //I don't know why this is created again 
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX booking__idx ON
    booking (
        customer_customer_id
    ASC );

ALTER TABLE booking ADD CONSTRAINT booking_pk PRIMARY KEY ( booking_id );
ALTER TABLE booking
    ADD CONSTRAINT booking_customer_fk FOREIGN KEY ( customer_customer_id )
        REFERENCES customer ( customer_id );

ALTER TABLE booking
    ADD CONSTRAINT booking_customer_fkv2 FOREIGN KEY ( customer_customer_id1 )
        REFERENCES customer ( customer_id );
```

CUSTOMER TABLE :

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
    customer_id         VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    first_name          VARCHAR(20),
    last_name           VARCHAR(30),
    booking_booking_id  INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX customer__idx ON
    customer (
        booking_booking_id
    ASC );

ALTER TABLE customer ADD CONSTRAINT customer_pk PRIMARY KEY ( customer_id );

ALTER TABLE customer
    ADD CONSTRAINT customer_booking_fk FOREIGN KEY ( booking_booking_id )
        REFERENCES booking ( booking_id );
```

Now whenever I try to insert a customer in mysql xampp server with typing

```
INSERT INTO customer('customer_id')VALUE("1234");
```

I get the error #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`airline_db`.`customer`, CONSTRAINT `customer_booking_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`booking_booking_id`) REFERENCES `booking` (`booking_id`)) which I have no idea why since the `customer_id` is the primary key and the `Booking.customer_id` the foreign key and I do not know why `booking_id` is included in this error
This is also how my entities look in data modeler :

[image]

I would really appreciate your help .

Answer (score 1):

you can't insert such  alues

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
    customer_id         VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    first_name          VARCHAR(20),
    last_name           VARCHAR(30),
    booking_booking_id  INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Means that you have at least  have to enter 1 booking_id which can't be NULL, but as you don't have a default values for it

Also a foreign key means that you have to have in booking such an id stored before you add a row in customers

Last you have a further problem, as you can only add a booking when you have a customer_id and vice versa , so get rid of the constraint in customer

Comment: You mean that I should get rid of booking_id foreign key in customer ? Which constraint ?

Comment: yes because 1 customer can have many bookings, but 1 bookling can have only one customer.